# TinyMCE - how to upload image

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm trying to upload an image, give it a class, and place it inside editor. Here is my complete tinymce code.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#editor",
    file_browser_callback_types: 'file image media',
    menubar: false,
    resize: false,
    statusbar: false,
    plugins: ["code autoresize autolink table image media"],
    toolbar1: "undo redo bold italic alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify fontsizeselect bullist numlist outdent indent backcolor image media",
     file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
            if(type=='image') $('#my_form input').click();
        },

    image_caption: true,
    image_description: false,
    image_dimensions: false,
    image_advtab: true,
    image_class_list: [
    {title: 'None', value: ''},
    {title: 'Dog', value: 'dog'},
    {title: 'Cat', value: 'cat'}
    ],
    style_formats: [
  {title: 'Image Left', selector: 'img', styles: {
    'float' : 'left',
    'margin': '0 10px 0 10px'
  }},
  {title: 'Image Right', selector: 'img', styles: {
    'float' : 'right',
    'margin': '0 10px 0 10px'
  }}
  ],
});
```

Click on img icon gives me the following popup.

[image]

But click on photo icon inside the popup is dead.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `file_picker_callback` function is not really doing anything ... what you need to do is have that function enable a process to pick a file.  The TinyMCE documentation has an example of this:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/file-picker/